# Bug in latest Xcode

Tags: javascript, xcode

Xcode `11.2 (11B52)` release seems to have a bug in indentation of *Javascript* code. A single slash seems to be getting treated as a start of a regexp.

An expression like `x = z*(3 +y/2);` gets treated as if the slash started a regexp which isn't closed, so the next line indent matches the open paren.

Anyone else seen this? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Although Xcode 11.2 is deprecated, I don't understand how did you face this issue. But you can update your Xcode if you believe it's a bug.

Comment: I think Xcode 11.2 is the latest version. It updated on Oct 31, 2019.

Comment: No It’s 11.2.1 GM seed now.